# PHP oci insert to return BLOB handle and record key

Tags: php, oracle, data-binding, sql-returning

I'm using Oracle oci in PHP.
Trying to implement an insert query for storing a child document/file record (with BLOB for contents) and returning the record key to store on the parent record.
I was hoping I could use the returning clause to return both the BLOB handle (standard practice) for storing the contents and the record key for passing back the record key (which is being set using a sequence and a trigger picking up on the lack of a value being passed to the key).
Anyway, I'm getting an error on the bind for the record key returning variable (asking for a descriptor). Am I just trying to do too much in one query?

Code is as follows:

Firstly, method to build and send the file insert call:

```
function insert_file($fcontents, $ftype, $fname, $fsize) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO ES_FILE (FILE_TYPE,FILE_NAME,FILE_CONTENTS,".
    "FILE_SIZE) ".
    "VALUES (?, ?, EMPTY_BLOB(), ?)";
    $fseq=$this->ora_lob_insert($sql,array($ftype, $fname, $fsize),
        'FILE_CONTENTS',$fcontents,'FILE_KEY');
    return $fseq;
}
```

Next, the standard method for inserting records containing a BLOB.
This is passed the insert query string, the array of bind variable values, the name of the BLOB column, the contents of the BLOB and now, the name of another column to be returned (ultimately as the return value of the method (if it is used).
This method is well tested before I added the additional feature of the extra return column/value...

```
public function ora_lob_insert($sql,$bindarr=array(),$lobcol='',$lobvar='',$other_retcol='') {
    Global $errormess;
    $retcol=0;
    // $sql must finish "RETURNING {lob_column} INTO :mylob" - Use EMPTY_CLOB() when inserting
    if (substr_count($sql,'?') != count($bindarr))
    { // number of ? in query string different to number of values in array
        $errormess='Error ora_bind_exec: Mismatch between query markers and bind values array!';
    }
    $i=0;
    $worked=false;
    foreach ($bindarr as $bindvar) {
        $sql=preg_replace('/\?/',":var${i}", $sql, 1);
        $i++;
    }
    if (!strcmp($other_retcol,'')) {
        $sql.=" RETURNING $lobcol INTO :mylob";
    } else {
        $sql.=" RETURNING $lobcol, $other_retcol INTO :mylob, :retcol";
    }
    $obf_parse=@oci_parse($this->connect,$sql);
    if ($obf_parse === false)
    { // Parse Failed
        $errormess='Error ora_lob_insert: Query Parse Failed!';
    }
    $myLOB = @oci_new_descriptor($this->connect, OCI_D_LOB);
    // Bind the returned Oracle LOB locator to the PHP LOB object
    @oci_bind_by_name($obf_parse, ":mylob", $myLOB, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
    if (strcmp($other_retcol,'')) {
        oci_bind_by_name($obf_parse, ":retcol", $retcol, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
    }
    $i=0;
    foreach ($bindarr as $bindvar) {
        @oci_bind_by_name($obf_parse,":var${i}",$bindarr[$i],-1);
        $i++;
    }
    $list=array();
    $obf_exec=@oci_execute($obf_parse,OCI_DEFAULT);
    if ($obf_exec === false)
    { // Execute Failed
        $errormess='Error ora_lob_insert: Query Execution Failed!'."($sql)";
    }
    // Now save a value to the LOB
    if ( !$myLOB->save($lobvar)) {
        // On error, rollback the transaction
        oci_rollback($this->connect);
        $errormess='Error ora_lob_insert: Failed savin BLOB!';
    } else {
        // On success, commit the transaction
        oci_commit($this->connect);
        $worked=true;
    }

    @oci_free_statement($obf_parse);
    if (!strcmp($other_retcol,'')) {
        return $worked;
    } else {
        return $retcol;
    }

}
```

On running, the line doing the oci_bind_by_name for the "retcol" is giving a PHP error and says "Unable to find descriptor property ...".

Documentation suggests only using descriptors for BLOB and FILE handling.

Am I just breaking the oci libraries by trying to do something too complex?

Comment: Is the definition of the value correct - `":retcol", $retcol, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);` or should it be an integer?

Comment: No it's not correct, thankyou. As is often the case, it was the bleeding obvious. Thanks again - that was it. The perils of cut and paste strikes again. Stick up the answer and proclaim my idiocy to the world.